# Unable to use callback method for custom data channel in Cast Companion Library

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I'm using the Cast Companion Library and want to receive messages from my custom receiver via a custom namespace.

I'm able to use other callback methods without issue, but when I try to add onMessageReceived() to my code, Eclipse will give this error:

The method onMessageReceived(CastDevice, String, String) of type new VideoCastConsumerImpl(){} must override or implement a supertype method

Here's the code:

```
private void setupCastListener() {
    mCastConsumer = new VideoCastConsumerImpl() {

        // THIS WORKS:
        @Override
        public void onApplicationConnected(ApplicationMetadata appMetadata,
                String sessionId, boolean wasLaunched) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "CAST APPLICATION CONNECTED");
        }

        // WONT LET ME ADD THIS:
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(CastDevice castDevice, String namespace, String message) {

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misread the documentation, but digging in the VideoCastManager code showed the correct callback method to override is:

```
       @Override
        public void onDataMessageReceived(String message) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "CAST RECEIVED MESSAGE");
        }
```

Comment: You are correct, I will update the docs for that in the next update, thanks for reporting that.